# Truffle Box at URL https://github.com/truffle-box/bare-box.git doesn't exist

Tags: truffle, error, truffle-box

I'm trying to initialize a directory with `truffle init`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Truffle Box at URL https://github.com/truffle-box/bare-box.git doesn't exist. If you believe this is an error, please contact Truffle support.
```

The git repository at https://github.com/truffle-box/bare-box.git does exist, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out on Truffle's [Gitter channel](http://gitter.im/ConsenSys/truffle) that something must have broken in version 4. I upgraded to version 5 and the issue is resolved.

How to upgrade (more information [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases)):

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
npm install -g truffle
```

Comment: Thanks Joel - This was driving me nuts.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when my truffle version was **4.1.14**.
When I upgraded to version **4.1.15** the issue was solved. I just had to run **npm i -g truffle@4.1.15**

Answer (score 1):

You can also upgrade to maintenance release of truffle v4 as below.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g truffle 
sudo npm install -g truffle@4.1.15
```

Truffle unbox and other command remains same.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. Finally found the answer.

Truffle has some **reserved words**. In my case test is a reserved word in truffle.